# php code for generate excel and hard enter

Tags: php, excel

```
        $column = str_replace(',',' ', $rows[address]);
        $column = addslashes($column);
        $column = str_replace("\n", " ",$column);
        $contents.= $column."\t";

        $contents.="\n";
    }
header("Content-type: application/ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Confirmed.xls");
print $contents;
```

How to put address field without replacing "/n", since it's a address field I want to show it in cell in a good way...replacing "returns" make my address in single line.

Comment: Get in the habit of using PHP's built-in fputcsv() function to make your life easire

Comment: I am looking at it....but I can remember I had problems since my fields had commas...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Creating spreadsheets can get tricky with many issues, when I encountered such problem I ended up splitting the address field into multiple columns. I wrote an article about this long time ago hope this helps http://www.anchorx.com/ali/2011/02/27/create-spreadsheet-with-php/

Comment: your php class is very good...i would like to use it from now on...but actually it does not have solution for my current problem...splitting address to multiple column will generate some messy things for me..in excel if we enter alt+enter that will generate line breaks inside cell itself...can we not generate that character?

Comment: As I said, I had problems with this specific issue and I solved it by splitting the content, many solutions suggested using \n in the cell, which worked for me, but I think I had problem with open office then and different operating systems, I really don't remember what issues I had with that, its been long time and I remember I ended up using multiple columns. Can you please post back if the \n work? I will test this again soon as I am developing something where I need to create spreadsheets again.